# WPF MultiBinding to Model.ChildProperty doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some labels on a form. Some work and some do not. The difference is the ones that don't work are set up as multi-bindings, but in this specific instance they won't seem to bind properly.

Here is an example of two Labels, one working, one not. They both share the same Grid as parent, and the object I'm binding to is set to the DataContext of the page, so they should be sharing Context as well.

The Context object essentially takes the form (abstracted for privacy/security)

```
class Model {
    public SubModel Parent {get;set;}
}
class SubModel {
    public string PropA {get;set;}
    public string PropB {get;set;}
    public string PropC {get;set;}
}
```

Works:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Parent.PropA}"/>
```

Doesn't Work:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="Parent.PropB"/>
            <Binding Path="Parent.PropC"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

I know that this syntax works, because I have some other MultiBindings that take this same form and work, the different being that their page is bound directly to "Parent", and their binding looks more like

```
<Binding Path="PropB"/>
```

The problem seems to be when using the  tag and trying to reference a child property of a child property of the binding Context. Why is this happening and how can I get around it?

I have also tried binding the DataContext of the Label itself to the Parent object, which also doesn't work.

Why is this happening and how can I get around it without creating a bunch of different DataContexts on containers and mucking about that way?

Comment: Take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studio. You are getting a binding error message.

Comment: You're right I am, it's asking me for a MultiValueConverter. Why do I need to specify a converter for this binding but don't if the same property is targetted as a top-level property?

Comment: The question is why are you using a Label instead of a TextBlock? Binding a TextBlock's Text property would work that way without a converter.

Comment: Because I didn't know that, and I saw no reason why DataBinding a string to a Label should work any differently than binding it to a TextBlock when Label works in other places? That solves my immediate problem tho, thanks.

Comment: Difference: `Label` is a `ContentControl`. It's main property is `Content` which takes an object and is usually displayed through a `ContentPresenter` unless you override it. A `TextBlock` has the `Text` property which takes just a `string`, no conversion required in your case.

Comment: Ah makes sense now, thanks! Textblock is much more appropriate here in that case. The only thing that still confuses me, is why does the first example, where this same value is bound to a Label, through the content property, but using the inline Binding syntax, still valid, while creating essentially the same binding using explicit Binding tags does not work? Is this just one of those things where I should just accept it and continue on with my day?

Comment: See @Clemens proposed answer below. It explains it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StringFormat` property of a binding is only applied when the source property of the binding is of type `string`.

The `Content` property of a Label is of type `object`, hence the `StringFormat` isn't applied, and the binding system complains about a missing multi-binding converter.

When you use a TextBlock instead of a Label, the target property would be `Text`, which is of type string. The StringFormat will therefore by applied:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="Parent.PropB"/>
            <Binding Path="Parent.PropC"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

---

Even with a single binding, the following works:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Parent.PropA, StringFormat=Content: {0}}"/>
```

But this won't:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Parent.PropA, StringFormat=Content: {0}}"/>
```

However, Label has a `ContentStringFormat` property:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Parent.PropA}" ContentStringFormat="Content: {0}"/>
```

Comment: Ahhh this makes way more sense to me now. Thanks for the explanation!